# Why does sim tool kit is not appearing?

Tags: sim-card, 9.0-pie

I'm using Asus Zenfone Max Pro M2. 
Running on stable pie.

But sim tool kit is not appearing in my phone.
Does that mean my sim card is corrupted?
I face slower download speed using it.
So when I've checked other sim card of same operator then there's no issue.

Comment: The SIM tool kit may not have a lauchable activity, so it would not appear in launcher app, but should appear in system apps list under Settings app. Also, I don't think there is any correlation between it and download speed.

Comment: But I experienced such thing if it is not appeared. It is present under system app.

Comment: When system app would be in launcher sim tool kit is appeared only when sim is inserted so I'm sure sim is corrupted.